# El ejecutable no encuentra la librería (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Hice una aplicación y en mi pc funciona perfectamente, pero cuando la convierto en ejecutable me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'C:\Users\Nello\output\contadorFlotante_conFont\tkextrafont'*

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema? El modulo lo instale con pip install y como dije, en mi pc funciona todo perfecto pero no logro correrlo en un ejecutable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had exactly the same problem, and basiclly I was searching on Google how to download 'correctly' tkextrafont because the error was about a folder that couldn't be found. So I used the command:
pip show tkextrafont
Basiclly for finding the PATH where pip installed this module, and after going to that PATH I just copied the folder with same name tkextrafont and paste it on the ubication of my exe file and it works, I hope it can solve your problem too.

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! El idioma oficial del sitio es el español. Traduce tu respuesta.